# ¿Como unir dos dataframe en función del index del tiempo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo dos dataframes, uno con los precios en función del tiempo y el otro con noticias en función del tiempo. Quiero unirlos en función del tiempo :

`df_news.head()` :

```
            name
createdAt   
2017-10-20  Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza sto...
2018-08-01  Gucci Joins Paris Fashion Week for Its Spring ...
2018-04-20  Gucci launches its new creative hub Gucci ArtL...
2017-10-20  Gucci to launch homeware line Gucci Decor - CP...
2017-12-07  GUCCI opens new store at Miami Design District...
```

`df.head()` :

```
    IsStitched  Close   open
Date            
2014-01-31  NaN 148.05  NaN
2014-02-07  NaN 147.50  148.05
2014-02-14  NaN 152.30  147.50
2014-02-21  NaN 151.45  152.30
```

Es posibile que hay fechas por lo cual tal vez hay múltiples noticias. En este caso les deseo agregarlas en un array : no más de una línea cada dia.

Entonces intenté :

1. Agrupar las noticias por fechas en una tabla.`df1 = df_news.astype(str).groupby('Date').agg(','.join)`

Pero no he logrado hacer la tabla, `df1` :

```
                                                         name
Date                                                         
2017-10-20  Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza sto...
2017-12-07  GUCCI opens new store at Miami Design District...
2018-01-12       Gucci opens Gucci Garden in Florence - LUXUO
2018-02-26  GUCCI's wild experiment with the Fall Winter 2...
2018-04-20  Gucci launches its new creative hub Gucci ArtL...
2018-08-01  Gucci Joins Paris Fashion Week for Its Spring ...
2018-08-09  Gucci Revamped London Flagship Store | The Imp...
...
```

Y luego :

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df, how='inner', on='Date')
merged_df.head()
```

Pero me da :

```
          Date                                               name IsStitched  \
0    2017-10-20  Gucci debuts art installation at its Ginza sto...        NaN   
1    2017-12-07  GUCCI opens new store at Miami Design District...        NaN   
2    2018-01-12       Gucci opens Gucci Garden in Florence - LUXUO        NaN   
3    2018-02-26  GUCCI's wild experiment with the Fall Winter 2...        NaN   
4    2018-04-20  Gucci launches its new creative hub Gucci ArtL...        NaN   
5    2018-08-01  Gucci Joins Paris Fashion Week for Its Spring ...        NaN   
6    2018-08-09  Gucci Revamped London Flagship Store | The Imp...        NaN   
7    2014-01-31                                                NaN        NaN   
8    2014-02-07                                                NaN        NaN
```

Como puede ver, las fechas no están en el orden correcto. **¿Cómo volver a poner las líneas en orden de las fechas ?**

## Para reproducir el ejemplo :

`df` :

```
# Lectura de datos
url = 'https://finance.services.appex.bing.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=160.1.KER.PAR&chartType=5y'
resp = requests.get(url=url)
prices_gucci = resp.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(prices_gucci[0]['Chart']['Series'])

# Corregir origen de timestamps
origen = df.loc[0, "T"]
df.loc[1:, "T"] = df.loc[1:, "T"] + origen

# Convertir a datetime
df["fecha"] = pd.to_datetime(df["T"], unit="m", origin=pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01'))

df['open']=df['P'].shift(1)
df = df.drop(columns=['T'])

df = df.rename(columns={'P':'Close','fecha':'Date'})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
df_news['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_news['Date']).dt.date

df = df[["Close","Date","open"]]
```

Comment: ¿Será mejor que saques del índice las fechas (`.reset_index()`) y luego uses las columnas para hacer un `group()`? Luego puedes hacerle un `aggregate()` con una función que convierta a lista las noticias del mismo día. De ese modo te aseguras de que sólo hay una fila por fecha. Luego puedes volver a colocarlo como índice y `sort_index()`. Tras eso, tal vez el `join` te funcione, aunque no entiendo bien por qué no funciona ahora.

Comment: @abulafia Gracias por el comentario. Estoy trabajando sobre la función que convierta a lista las noticias del mismo dia. Sin embargo como utilisar la columnas de las fechas con [group()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) ? ¿Entonces tengo que hacer una función que agregue texto y datos numéricos a través de expresiones regulares?

Comment: @abulafia ¡Encontré la razón del error! `You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concate` Parece que las fechas no están en el mismo tipo

Comment: Ah, el tipo "object" suele referirse a un string. Parece que en uno de tus dataframes el `index` no es de tipo `datetime`, sino cadenas. Ya sabes como resolverlo, debes usar `pd.to_datetime()`